# javascript event listener

Tags: java, javascript, browser

I am developing a web browser in java. For parsing and rendering I am using cobra 0.98.4 .
cobra is not  cookie enabled . So to save cookie I create a cookie management class. I can extract cookie from a web page . But I don't know how to send it. I know that to send cookie I have to set property of URL-Connection and create an URL-connection. Because different website use java-script button for log-in.My main problem is that I can not listen a java-script event . How can I listen a java-script event in java ? I need to know the button event to create an connection to server to send the cookie that was extracted from the last page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say you are developing a new browser? what do you use for javascript compiler? you know, like IE has jscript mozilla has .. something else, can't remember right now. Anyhow in order to create an event listener you will need some kind of hook method something like:

if (myButton.onClick && typeOf(myButton.onClick) == "function"){ // on click event is attached
 
   if (!myButton.onClick(event)){
     
   break;
   
 }

}

I mean if you truly developing a new browser you should have a place where you already defined the 'click' event in order to do some kind of animation or even postbacks or so and there would be the place to define a "hook" method.

Comment: cobra use mozilla rhino compiler for java-script . My problem is that every single web-page is different from others . So the orientation , number of java-script  buttons are different. how can I declare  a single variable of button and attach an event listener to the button. Is it clear to you what is my problem ? Besides I am using  cobra(for parsing & rendering ) . It parses the whole HTML page into a DOM document and renders it graphically to a J-component and also compile java-script contents. I don't find any method to access the URL-connection from outside of the api for setting cookie.

Comment: I'm afraid I can't help you there too much as I'm not too familiar with the way cobra works, "Cobra can be used as a Javascript-aware and CSS-aware HTML parser, independently of the Cobra rendering engine. Javascript DOM modifications that occur during parsing (e.g. via document.write) will be reflected in the parsed DOM, unless Javascript is disabled. " is any javascript code working? because if it works document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0].onclick should be available to you for attaching an event.

Comment: I don't understand your question " is any java-script code working?" Using this api I able to implement the java-script content of a web-page.

Comment: the question is exactly that: is javascript parsed and are you able to run let's say a simple alert?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the click event to a function to call your server script.

```
YOUR_BUTTON.onclick = function(){

  // Send require here.
}
```

You may post some sample code you working on in order we can help.